# How to generate pixelated or blurry previews thumbnails in iOS or via node.js?

Tags: image-processing, uiimageview, imagemagick

I want to have a feature where a thumbnails of uploaded photos is pixelated or blurry with a touch icon overly on top, so that a user will have to hold on the thumbnail if they want to view the full unobscured photo.

Is there a way to get ios to generate the pixelated thumbnails before uploading them to the server?  Should I just use a ridiculous jpeg compression value?

Or, should I do this server side using Node.js and ImageMagick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it pretty simply with ImageMagick like this:

```
convert MrBean.jpg -scale 10% -scale 1000% MrPixel.jpg
```

which turns this:

[image]

into this:

[image]